Transition between tile in bathroom and engineered hardwood with small height diffference
we are in the middle of installing tile in our bathroom. We have laid the membrane down. At this point we are trying to decide how to do the transition to the hallway.
Based on the assumption that the mortar will add about ~1/8'', it seems that the tile will end up approximately 2-3mm higher than the engineered hardwood.
Is there an easy way to match the height of the tile to the floor? Alternatively, is this height difference large enough that I should use a tile to floor reducer (like this reducer) or can I get away with a same height transition (like this T transition or this profile transition)

Why not a threshold? Seems like the obvious thing.

Will the tile butt up against the long side of the hardwood, or the ends of the planks?  How thick are the tiles?

@Huesmann Long side of the hardwood not the ends. And tiles are I think 9mm - not at home to verify right now

@thatguy14 if the tile butts up against the long side, rather than using a tee transition, I would try wedging the board up by 2-3mm (depends on layout, can you show us a pic?) to meet the tile.  Or carefully taper grind the adjacent tiles by 2-3mm.  Or simply use a marble transition bar like thousands of other bathroom transitions do.

If the difference was only going to be 2mm, you could get by with a "T" transition. The wood ones would be better.  The problem is all my tile jobs have ended up with close to 7mm of mortar so the "T" wouldn't work. I've had to use a threshold between the two surfaces. This would actually be good using a marble one because the bathroom floor will get wet and you won't want that moisture getting under the wood flooring.

+1.  Stone thresholds are an excellent choice for wet areas, but awareness of them seems not to have been adopted into the design culture in some areas. When we were redoing the flooring and I specified thresholds, I had several contractors say something along the lines of “what, you mean like in a hotel?”

Marble transition is an interesting idea. Is it typical to use marble transition with porcelain tile? I'd point out as well that the tile we chose is very glossy so maybe this wouldn't look right.

@thatguy14   It is very typical to use it with porcelain tile.  Many home and tile stores supply them in 36" lengths and in different colors for this exact purpose.  Typical dimensions  might be 5/8" high and 2" wide with beveled edges.

You can get marble and granite thresholds that are highly polished (glossy), if you like. Honestly I don't think the look needs to match particularly when it's also a transition between two differenf floor types, so it's not going to "match" at least one of them. Not matching either is OK in that situation. But shiny rocks can be had from any decent supplier. 2, 4 & 6 inches are typical widths with a few 5 inch showing up in search results.
